# MVP, struggling to populate View's RibbonDropDown with Interface Property

Tags: c#, mvp, ribbon-control

I think my question is fairly trivial, but I'm not getting my problem right. I want to use a passive-Presenter in the MVP pattern. My present concrete view is an Excel Add-in, but I don't want this to limit me in future.

On this view I have a RibbonDropDown, the items I need to get from the Model, and pass to the View via the Presenter. I also want an Interface between the Presenter and View so that they are more loosely coupled.

This [MVP example](http://www.contentedcoder.com/2012/04/mvp-design-pattern-survival-kit.html) was quite useful, but it seems I can't bind the datasource like they've done here to their example of a list of products:

```
 public IList<ProductItem> Products
{
    set
    {
        this.uiProducts.DataSource = value;
        this.uiProducts.DataBind();
    }
}
```

So, if this is my Presenter:

```
public class Presenter 
{
    private IViewInterface iView;

    public Presenter(IViewInterface pView)
    {
        iView = pView;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        
        List<String> ServArr = new List<String>();
        ServArr.Add("a server 1");
        ServArr.Add("a server 2");
        iView.ServArr = ServArr;     
    }

}
```

and this is the interface for the View:

```
public interface IViewInterface
{
    List<String> ServArr { get; set; }
}
```

and this is a snippet of the View:

```
public partial class SympivotyRibbon : IViewInterface
{

    private Presenter presenter;
   
    public List<String> ServArr
    {
        set { ServArr = new List<String>(value); }
        //get { return ServArr; }
    }

    private void SympivotyRibbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {

        presenter = new Presenter(this);
        presenter.Initialize();

       for (int i = 0; i < ServArr.Count; i++)
       {
           RibbonDropDownItem item = Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
           item.Label = ServArr[i];
           dropDownServer.Items.Add(item);
       }

    }
    
}
```

Then I get the compiler error in the for-loop:

> The property or indexer 'SympivotyRibbon.ServArr' cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor

I don't know how to put in a getter together with the setter, so that I can populate the control. If I uncomment the get-part above, I get a StackOverflow exception, probably because it is circular.

I assume the answer should be easy, I just don't know how.